# join data with mysql and php

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i have 2 tables:

```
 TABLE USER
ID | USER | PASSWORD
1 | john | xxx
2 | max | xxx
3 | carl | xxx
4 | marie | xxx
5 | andy | xxx
```

TABLE FRIENDS
ID | iduser | idfriends
1 | 1 | 2
2 | 1 | 3
3 | 2 | 1
4 | 2 | 4
5 | 2 | 5
6 | 2 | 3 
7 | 3 | 1

how can i get all friends johns?

Comment: in title you say mysql and php; your tags are mysql and sql... so, which tags are the ones for you? ;)

Comment: Be aware not to store passwords in plain text in your db ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.* FROM FRIENDS f
INNER JOIN `USER` u
ON f.idfriends=u.id
WHERE f.iduser=1;
```

Comment: just giving the id of the user may not be the most helpful.  I imagine you would have to do a sub query to know the id that would need to be used

Comment: @John No sub-query required, simply `INNER JOIN User u2 ON f.iduser = u2.ID WHERE u2.User = 'john'`

Comment: @John: yes, but probably he shows a list of users (selecting from USERS table) and, after selecting one user (for which he already knows id), he show his friends...

Comment: @Marco My thoughts exactly :-)

Comment: what I meant was in the where clause you limit the results by the users id.  Which would not be associated with a specific user unless there was a separate query to associate 'john' with an id of 1.

Comment: @John, as I've already told you (and that's @Phil Brown's idea too) is that he knows specific user-id, because probably he has a previous query to get (and show) all users. When the end user select a specific user he gets his friends... if I have an app to write, I'll write it in this way...

Comment: I am not disagreeing with that, the author of the question did not specify what was known, so I was just stating the obvious.  If you do not have the users id you have to get it.

Comment: @John That's fine, but a sub-query is not the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.user 
FROM user u 
LEFT JOIN friends f ON u.id=f.idfriends 
WHERE f.iduser = (SELECT id FROM user WHERE user = 'john');
```

Comment: Instead of using a sub-query, it would be much more efficient to simply join on `User` again using a different alias.